# Eloquent model object not recognized_ laravel course excerice

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Following an online course on Laravel I got stuck, and I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
I have the following code in my project:

**`web.php`**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
 
Route::get('/pizzas', 'PizzaController@index');
Route::get('/pizzas/{id}','PizzaController@show');
```

**`Pizza.php`**

```
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Pizza extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
// protected $tabel = 'pizzas';
}
```

**`PizzaController.php:`**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Pizza;
 
class PizzaController extends Controller
{
//
public function index(){
    
    $pizzas = Pizza::all();
    
    return view('pizzas', [
        'pizzas'=>$pizzas,
        ]);
 
}
 
public function show($id){
    return view('details', ['id'=> $id]);
}
```

**`Pizza.blade.php:`**

```
<h1> Pizza List </h1>              
      
@foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
   <div>
    {{ $pizza->$name }}    // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
   </div> 
@endforeach
```

Error message:

```
ErrorException 
Trying to get property '' of non-object (View:  D:\xxxxxxxxxxx\laravel\pizzahouse1\resources\views\pizzas.blade.php) 
http://localhost:8000/pizzas
     
error in line 21
```

Comment: try Pizza::with([])->get(); instead in the controller

Comment: Remove $ from name property `$pizza->name`

Comment: When I call $pizza->name I get the following error: 

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: Put `dump($pizza);` into loop (delete all other things) so you will see what type is variable in each iteration. Also, before `@foreach` you can set `@if($pizzas->isNotEmpty())`. To skip loop if collection is not iterable.

Comment: @M.Koops {{{ isset($pizza->name) ? $pizza->name : '' }}}

Comment: @M.Koops please check it's working or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1> Pizza List </h1>              
      
@foreach($pizzas as $pizza)
   <div>
    {{ $pizza->$name }}    // HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
   </div> 
@endforeach
```

Why you are using "$name"?
Error says ,

> You are calling for a property that doesn't exists in $pizza.

it should be something like following:

```
{{ $pizza->name }}
```

If problem still exists just :

```
dd($pizza);
```

Then see the results and call the property.
Hope it would help.

Comment: I use $name, because the tutorial does so....

dd($pizza); generates the output:

dd($pizza);
dd($pizza);
dd($pizza);

( I have three records in the database...)

When I do: 

{{ $pizza->name }}

I get error: 
 Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: use this . to be specific . <?php dd($pizza); ?>  
You have to php tag to execute php code in blade. 
@M.Koops

Comment: OK, thanks Shifat.
Now I get:
array:2 [▼
  "type" => "hawaiian"
  "base" => "chessy crust"
]

Comment: bit strange since I have 3 records, only first is showing.

Comment: @M.Koops  use <?php dd($pizzas); ?> to see all data

Comment: @M.Koops  You can debug and solve your problem. Please accept it as answer if you want. Thanks

Comment: I did uncomment extension=pdo_mysql  in php.ini earlier, because of error messages. Can that have to do anything with it?

Comment: @M.Koops No. because if it is related with mysql then you will not get any data at all.

Comment: what are the columns you have in your pizza table?

Comment: Thnaks for helping!      columns are: id, created_at, updated_at, type, base, name

Comment: @M.Koops why you are using HasFactory? show me the code

Comment: hasFactory was created by default, when creating the model using artisan, I tried removing it.  Yet I seem to have solved it; no IDEA what I did!!  I ran composer install in another directory, for another project, after that PizzaController could not be found, I explicitely pit the namespace in the route and now  everything works !?!?

Comment: @M.Koops {{{ isset($pizza->name) ? $pizza->name : '' }}}